# How to find out what the EDT is doing when the app hangs on iOS?

Tags: codenameone

I have a funny behavior with my app on iOS (did not check out on Android yet).  While the app seems to run fine in the CN1 simulator, it hangs on some UI updates on the first form first display right after the splashscreen.  I see from the iOS logs that some background tasks are still running as expected.  Any way to find out what the EDT is stuck with?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards,

Emmanuel

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Mac the best way to debug these things is to run within xcode and use its debugger as [explained here](https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---use-the-include-sources-feature-to-debug-the-native-code-on-iosandroid-etc.html). If you don't have a Mac you can't really track the EDT on the device. You would need to make assumptions and logging to guess the source of the issue and then go through trial and error to locate it.

Comment: To see the EDT logs and other thread logs there are also other ways. For example, I use https://www.browserstack.com/app-live in which I can see the full logs and I can filter them: I think that this is the simpler and more efficient way to see logs without a MacOS. Another approach that I use, but that is very very complex and it requires a very performing computer, is the use of MacOS + Xcode inside a virtual machine, with a working usb connection to an iPhone: it's very hard to make it working, but it's not impossible. However BrowserStack App Live is the simplest solution.

Comment: Hello @shai-almong, thanks for your response an dfor your help.  I managed to load the app in the xcode simulator.  I wonder now where I can put my breakpoint to start looking at what the EDT is doing on a user events as it seems none of these are processed.

Francesco, thanks for the tip.  Fortunately, I have a Mac.

Comment: You can just press pause in the debugger to see what's happening at a given moment. While the code might not be readable the stack trace of the threads on the side should be readable.

Comment: Thanks.  I see where it's stuck now.